# Do you lose/gain rating if you withdraw in the middle of an OTB tournament?

Tags: rules, fide, rating, tournament, round-robin

Magnus just withdrew from the Sinquefield Cup. Does that affect his rating at the end of the tournament? Will he gain or lose rating based on at the time he left the tournament in the next fide update?

Side question - Does that also mean that Nepo's and Aronian's results will be converted as win (without rating changes) because otherwise it will be unfair in a round-robin situation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simple rule is that FIDE rates games where at least one move has been made and the FIDE Laws of Chess applied. You can read the full rules [here](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022022). That means that his next FIDE rating will be based on the games he has played so far this month plus any more he might play. The only way you can gain or lose rating points is by playing FIDE rated chess.

> Does that also mean that Nepo's and Aronian's results will be converted as win(without rating changes) because otherwise it will be unfair in a round-robin situation?

This is covered in the [FIDE Tournament Rules](https://handbook.fide.com/files/handbook/Competition_Rules.pdf):

> **6.6 Round robins**
> (1) Each player has entered into a contract to play throughout the tournament.
> (2) When a player withdraws or is expelled from a tournament, the effect shall be as follows:
>
> 1. If a player has completed less than 50 % of his games, the results shall remain in the tournament table (for rating and historical purposes), but they shall not be counted in the final standings. The unplayed games of the player are indicated by (-) in the tournament table and those of his opponents by (+). If neither player is present this will be indicated by two (-).
> 2. If a player has completed at least 50 % of his games, the results shall remain in the tournament table and shall be counted in the final standings. The unplayed games of the player are shown as above.

So, completed games will be rated. If Carlsen has completed 50% of his games then his remaining opponents will have their results against him recorded as wins for the tournament but not rated, since no moves were played. In effect he has defaulted his remaining games.

Comment: I would think awarding a withdrawn or disqualified player wins for unplayed games would grossly unfairly benefit the would-be opponents.  I would think it would be fairer to treat the score unplayed game as being the average of the other games where the player had the same color.

Comment: @supercat or do what they do when less than 50% of the games have been played and just annul all results for fairness.

Comment: @qwr Annulling all results would be unfair to the opponents he already played, right? That's why the threshold is 50%?

Comment: @justhalf yes they would waste effort and either go up or down in the standings based on their performances, but the round-robin system is designed for everyone to play each other so some compromise has to be made

Comment: @qwr: I was also pondering what would be the best way of handling a situation (e.g. death in the family) that would not render a player incapable of playing, but would grossly interfere with a player's ability to play well.  If a player who has yet to face one opponent is in such a situation, having them play on when unable to do so effectively would essentially offer that opponent an unearned "free win", which would seem more disruptive of overall standings than awarding a fractional-point bye for the opponent.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your side question, the competitors who faced Magnus already will have their results annulled (but still count for rating points), and the competitors who haven't faced Magnus yet will get a bye. Effectively this is now a "9 player tournament" where all the matchups with Magnus are now treated as byes.

Source: [Saint Louis Chess Club Executive Director Tony Rich Interview on Day 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VElLYxf08C0)

Nepo benefits since his round 1 loss against Carlsen is erased, while Niemann is hindered since his surprise win against Carlsen is also erased. Aronian drew against Magnus so he neither gains nor loses.

[Caruana interview: "Ian is obviously the biggest beneficiary in terms of the tournament"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXm530tI-B8)